# Trying to select a files location + file name in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, filepath, file-browser, urlrequest

I am creating a file testing program in actionscript 3. I have the URL loader to load the file path + name typed in the textbox. However I am looking to upgrade the experience. I am trying to find a way to choose a file location and name from a function like browseforDirectory(). If anyone could help with providing me either a link to documentation on how to do this or if anyone could help me out that would be awesome. For an example of how its set up currently.

```
public var TestPath:string = this.TestTxt.txt;
..

this.ldr.load(new URLRequest(TestPath));
```

This is pretty much a simple example of what would be going on. I am just looking for a way to find a file via browsing for it in a file select window and save the complete path of the file. Sorry if I sound repetitive and all help is appreciate. Couldn't find any documentation towards this specific topic.

Comment: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()

Comment: Solved. Thank you organis for the very distant poke in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do it. Thank you for pointing me to browse Organis. I think explaining the use of browse a little more, or even providing a quick sample, would have proved to create an excellent answer that others who might view this topic would find helpful. Here is what I have used. It is quite crude and I will refine it later.

```
package  {

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.net.FileFilter;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.filesystem.File;


public class Browse extends MovieClip 
{
    var File1:File = new File();


    public function Browse() 
    {
            //Adds an event listener for the selected file.
            File1.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, FileSelected);
            //Narrows down the file selection
            var swfTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Text Files","*.txt; *.png;*.as");
            var allTypeFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("All Files (*.*)","*.*");
            //Calls the browse function to pop up a file selection window
            File1.browse([swfTypeFilter, allTypeFilter]);
    }

    function FileSelected(event:Event):void
    {
        trace(File1.nativePath);
    }

}
```

}

Hopefully anyone looking for a way just to get a file path of a file selected can find it here.